# TextField() Set caret position

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How to set the caret position, there is only

> this.caretIndex (READ)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use `setSelection(beginIndex:int, endIndex:int):void`

eg

```
this.textField.setSelection(20, 20)
```